# Bootstrap site is printing links

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

When I try to physically print a page from my bootstrap site it prints the relevant links too. I've never seen this behavior before. I looked it up online but can't seem to find a working solution.

For example I have a link:

```
Link to another page
(example.php)
```

I'm really not sure what to do and it's quite annoying. Any help would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bootstrap comes with many default styles (obviously), one of them being the ability to print the URL next to links. In the Bootstrap CSS file you'll find:

```
@media print {
...
    a[href]:after {
        content: " (" attr(href) ")"
    }
...
}
```

This takes the URL and appends it to the link within parenthesis. One easy way to kill this behavior is to override Bootstrap's rule with your own (loaded after the Bootstrap CSS) and for content use `content:none`:

```
a[href]:after {
    content: none;
}
```

Comment: This did the trick. I couldn't find the code for a while but I got it. Thanks. Also, why would anyone want this feature by default? Makes no sense to me.

Comment: It was  more popular a while ago. Guess the BS folks thought it could still be useful.

Comment: [It's part of HTML5 Boilerplate.](https://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate/blob/712568f229fd8b25bbd8a76f2908bad1fea3fc62/src/css/main.css#L218)

Answer (score 0):

To not have the links printed, use CSS:

```
a:link:after, a:visited:after{
    content: "";
}
```